# Why "npx expo start" command doesn't work?

Tags: react-native, npm, expo, npx

`npx expo start` command doesn't work. I have been producing amateur projects using expo for a while now.

There has been no problem so far, but the `npx expo start` command is not working right now. It doesn't give an error either. It doesn't give any reaction. I am using **VSCode** btw.

I can't upload the screenshot due to server problems, but it would look like this:

PS C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\EcoScan> npx expo start

PS C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\EcoScan>

Comment: On one of my machines, running expo start with npx causes a considerable delay compared to running without npx. Are you sure you're waiting long enough to be sure the server starts? an error should be thrown if something is going wrong.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure I've waited long enough. I have done this process before and it was working smoothly. It's not reacting at all right now, like in the photo.

Comment: I can't upload the screenshot due to server problems, but it would look like this:
PS C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\EcoScan> npx expo start
PS C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\EcoScan>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted the .expo folder from my computer and reinstalled it, it fixed itself. I think it was a problem with the update.